# RestAssured Error - Specification to merge with cannot be null

Tags: java, junit5, rest-assured

I'm getting the error message "Specification to merge with cannot be null" when I try to run the code in ResourcesAPI. Can you help me ?

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setUp() {

    String auth = TokenManager.getAuthToken();

    setAuthentication(
            new RequestSpecBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", auth)
                    .build());


    setBaseUriAndContentTypeToJson(
            new RequestSpecBuilder()
                    .setBaseUri(ApiEndPoints.BASE_ENDPOINT)
                    .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                    .build());

    setResponseSpec(
            new ResponseSpecBuilder()
                    .expectStatusCode(200)
                    .expectContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                    .build());
    }
}
```

Token Manager Class

```java
package utils;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

public class TokenManager extends Specifications {
    private static final String GET_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://dummyjson.com/auth/login";
    private static final String REQUEST_BODY = "{ \"username\": \"kminchelle\", \"password\": \"0lelplR\" }";
    private static String authToken;
    private static volatile long tokenExpirationTimeMillis;
    private static final long TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DURATION_MILLIS = 3600000;


    public static String getAuthToken() {
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (authToken == null || currentTimeMillis >= tokenExpirationTimeMillis) {
            authToken = extractJsonWebToken();
            tokenExpirationTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DURATION_MILLIS;
        }
        return authToken;
    }

    private static String extractJsonWebToken() {
        authToken = "Bearer " +

                given()
                        .spec(getBaseUriAndContentTypeToJson())
                        .body(REQUEST_BODY)
                        .log().all()
                .when()
                        .post(GET_TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
                .then()
                        .extract()
                        .path("token");

        System.out.println("Token " + authToken);
        return authToken;
    }
}
```

Example of application of specifications

```
public class ResourcesAPI extends Specifications {

    @Test
    public void shouldAcessUserResources() {

        given()
                .spec(getBaseUriAndContentTypeToJson())
                .spec(getAuthentication())
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .get(ApiEndPoints.LOGIN_ENDPOINT)
                .then()
                .spec(getResponseSpec())
                .log().all();
    }
```

I'm trying to add token generation directly to the request specifications so that it is added to all tests.

Error:

```
Test ignored.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specification to merge with cannot be null
```

Comment: Please checkout: "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @Matheus: one of `getBaseUriAndContentTypeToJson()` & `getAuthentication()` is null. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the TokenManager class.

public class TokenManager{

private static final String GET_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://dummyjson.com/auth/login";

private static final String REQUEST_BODY = "{ "username": "kminchelle", "password": "0lelplR" }";

public static String getAuthToken(){

```
    return "Bearer " +

                     given()
                             .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                             .body(REQUEST_BODY)
                    .when()
                             .post(GET_TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
                    .then()
                             .extract()
                             .path("token");
}
```

}

Comment: Please, format your answer properly